# how to stop initial jump of the attributes while using setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using set interval for displaying a dynamic data in progress but here my issue is on the initial start of the page it is kind of jumping the elements and then displaying the data .how can i stop that jump and here on initial my progress bar is also showing from middle not from the start

```js
var timerId = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadData();
});

function loadData() {
  var data = {
    information: {
      "num": 73.00,
      "value": 75
    }
  }
  var i = 0;
  var maxValue = data["information"]["value"];

  timerId = setInterval(function() {

    data.information.value += 1;
    data.information.num += 0.01;
    let tri = data.information.num.toFixed(2);
    $('.animation').text(tri);
    $('.process').text(data.information.value);
    $('#blips > .progress-bar').css("width", data.information.value + "%");
    i++;
    if (data.information.value == 100) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }
  }, 1000)

}

$('#stop').click(function() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
});
```

```css
.text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 19%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  width: 62%;
}

.nimation {}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: brown !important;
  width: 244px;
  height: 44px;
}

#stop {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 112px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-top: 46px;
  width: 288px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: brown;
  color: white;
}

.process {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 26%;
}

.para {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: black;
  margin-top: -5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="text">
      <p class="animation"> </p>
      <p class="para">Data</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="progress" id="blips">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar">
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="process"></p>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="stop">Stop</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have css issues, if you dont want things to jump around, better don't use `position: absolute;`, use `position: relative;`, give the divs height and width, so you have reserved the space, if the text are displayed after or will stay empty no matter, the information will have their spaces... Everything will stay like it should, just that text will be displayed after...

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that updates the DOM from the `data` object in a separate function that you call before starting the interval timer, so that you'll display the data with the initial values first.

```js
var timerId = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadData();
});

function loadData() {
  var data = {
    information: {
      "num": 73.00,
      "value": 75
    }
  }
  var i = 0;
  var maxValue = data["information"]["value"];

  function displayProgress() {
    let tri = data.information.num.toFixed(2);
    $('.animation').text(tri);
    $('.process').text(data.information.value);
    $('#blips > .progress-bar').css("width", data.information.value + "%");
  }
  displayProgress();
  timerId = setInterval(function() {

    data.information.value += 1;
    data.information.num += 0.01;
    displayProgress();
    i++;
    if (data.information.value == 100) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }
  }, 1000)

}

$('#stop').click(function() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
});
```

```css
.text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 19%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  width: 62%;
}

.nimation {}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: brown !important;
  width: 244px;
  height: 44px;
}

#stop {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 112px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-top: 46px;
  width: 288px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: brown;
  color: white;
}

.process {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 26%;
}

.para {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: black;
  margin-top: -5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="text">
      <p class="animation"> </p>
      <p class="para">Data</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="progress" id="blips">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar">
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="process"></p>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="stop">Stop</button>
  </div>
</div>
```